# Doctrine bulk DQL update with join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to update a large collection of entities (~100k) with a few set of values. To do this, I want to use a [DQL update Query](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#dql-update).

The problem came from the where clause of my query. I need to filter the entities to update.

```
$qb->update('MyBundle/Entity/MyEntity', 'e')
->set('e.fieldToUpdate', ':value')
->innerJoin('e.relation', 'r')
->where('r.filter < :filter')
->setParameters...
```

Unfortunatly joins are not supported on update and delete queries.
And I won't be able to use a where clause with `e.id IN "subquery"` since MySQL documentation says :

> In MySQL, you cannot modify a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

I'd like to avoid using `Query#iterate()` facility  or other solutions based on loop for performance reason, so...I don't know how to deal with this.

It sounds like a common problem, and I may miss something very obvious...so if there is a workaround to do this, i'll be glad to read it !

Comment: Have you tried to use subquery and raw sql? It might help you.

Comment: how about first select entity ids by querying only relation table. and then updating entity table ? check batch processing here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html Also, disable SQL logger: http://konradpodgorski.com/blog/2013/01/18/how-to-avoid-memory-leaks-in-symfony-2-commands/

Comment: I'm confident about a raw SQL solution,  but if it's possible, I prefer to stay with DQL for readability. @Miro : That's a good idea indeed, i'll take à look. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Miro, I found a pretty obvious solution (of course)...

Since I can't select inside the subquery the same table I'm updating, I had to select the relation, from another table.

Doctrine doesn't allow to select something like `r.mytable` where 'mytable` is the Entity I am targeting, but, there is a DQL function to do this : IDENTITY

For instance :

```
    $dql = $queryBuilder
        ->from('Relation', 'r')
        ->select('IDENTITY(r.myEntity)')
        ->where('r.filter > :filter')
        ->getDQL()
    ;  

    $queryBuilder = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('e')
        ->update('MyBundle/Entity/MyEntity', 'e')
        ->set('e.fieldToUpdate', ':value')
        ->where(
            $queryBuilder->expr()->In('e.id', $dql)
        )
        ->setParameters([
            'filter'      => $filter
        ]);
```